# Tool to compare the data of two databases (REDSHIFT)

Tags: database, amazon-redshift

I'm looking for a tool to compare the **data** of two databases (data, not schema!). The two databases are Redshift db.

So far I've only tried the trial version of Aqua Data Studio (http://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio.html) but it doesn't have all the functionalities I need.

Any suggestion? There are many tools available but I don't find any that supports Redshift!

EDIT:

Functionalities I need:

- compare two tables and display the rows that are different,
- display which are the different columns in each of the different rows with their values.

Comment: What functionalities do you need?

Comment: I made an edit with the functionalities I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For schema compare and convert look at www.dbschema.com [DbSchema Designer](http://www.dbschema.com). It can manage large schemes and generates nice diagrams.[Sample DbSchema diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wbOe.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found **Database Compare Suite** which I haven't tried. This is not an opensource but its worth to try. It supports Amazon Redshift, Microsoft Azure SQL Database, IBM DB2, Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and Sybase ASE. Check in the below link

https://www.dbbest.com/blog/database-compare-suite-amazon-redshift-sql-server-2000-support/